# Badge count font size is way too small on beta sites

Tags: bug, design, beta-sites, font-size

[image: screenshot]

Why are the numbers so much smaller than the "awarded" text? It looks quite awkward.

(The number is 10px, and "awarded" is 13px.)

Answer (score 2):

All the sites now have the same font size, it seems, whether they're in beta or are graduated.

> [image]

So this is now fixed.